# Error settting up atom with nodejs on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I am trying to set up nodejs with atom on ubuntu 16.10. I followed the steps given in [this link](https://subhadipsblog.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/developing-node-js-with-atom-editor/). But when I edit the `~/.atom/config.cson` file to

```
runner:

scopes:

js:”nodejs”
```

as given in the link, Atom gives an error

```
Unexpected new line after runner:
```

How do I get this correct?

**EDIT**
After using Dan Lowe's code, the atom error disappeared but the code doesnt compile.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/');
```

It gives the error

```
./server.js: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./server.js: line 3: `var http = require('http');'
```

Is it not able to see nodejs?

Comment: IMO, this edit probably should be a separate question. You've moved on to a completely different situation/problem now.

Comment: @DanLowe : Done - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580416/error-when-running-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the actual config you are using, you have two problems.

1. The lines are not indented.
2. Around `nodejs` are smart-quotes, not normal double quotes. That is not valid syntax here.

You probably want this instead.

```
runner:
  scopes:
    js: "nodejs"
```

Comment: The error doesn' come now. But the simple programe that I added in the edit won't even compile. I am not sure it is able to see nodejs.